# How does magento know the table name

Tags: magento2, table

I am confused about magento table name defenation.

Here in magento 1 we was define in `entity` tag in which table name and entity was defined.

But in magento2 nothing like that .

So my question is where does it goes to find it like

```
$installer->getTable('helloworld')
```

Comment: you want to get Table name in Installer Script or Upgrade Script?

Comment: No i just want to know how it works

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2, you dont have to define Table Name in **config.xml** file.

Here is the blog for setup script and creating new Table in Magento Database. Hope it will clear your confusion

http://inchoo.net/magento-2/setup-scripts-magento-2/

Comment: Sorry Abhishek.but still not satisfied answer.I would like to know from where magento does know that `$installer->getTable('helloworld')` is asking for `helloworld` table.